# Group data.frame by multiple columns

Tags: r

Say I have this data.frame

```
data <- data.frame(foo = c(1, 1, 2, 2 ),
                   bar = c(10,10,10,20),
                   baz = c(1, 2, 3, 4 ),
                   qux = c(5, 6, 7, 8 ))
```

I want to group it by the `foo` and `bar` columns to arrive at this:

```
expected <- list(
  data.frame(foo = c(1, 1),
             bar = c(10, 10),
             baz = c(1, 2),
             qux = c(5, 6)),
  data.frame(foo = 2,
             bar = 10,
             baz = 3,
             qux = 7),
  data.frame(foo = 2,
             bar = 20,
             baz = 4,
             qux = 8)
)
```

I can generate a frame with a row for each group, but I couldn't find a `MATCH` function; something that when given an input frame with columns `foo,bar,baz,qux` and a filter frame with columns `foo,bar` returns the rows where the `foo,bar` cell's content matches.

```
groups <- unique(data[c("foo","bar")])
MATCH(data, groups[1,]) == expected[[1]]
MATCH(data, groups[2,]) == expected[[2]]
MATCH(data, groups[3,]) == expected[[3]]
```

Or a higher level `GROUP` function which just returns a list of frames, where the columns given match:

```
GROUP(data, by=c("foo","bar")) == expected
```

The closest I came to that is

```
out <- aggregate(. ~ foo + bar, data, list)
```

Where the cells `baz`, `qux` are lists:

```
> out
  foo bar  baz  qux
1   1  10 1, 2 5, 6
2   2  10    3    7
3   2  20    4    8
> class(out[,"baz"])
[1] "list"
```

So each group is a row in `out`, but how do I unfold this again, so that `out[1,]` becomes a data.frame with two rows, like `expected[[1]]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you just need `split`.

**Option 1**: Retaining all "levels" of the combination of "foo" and "bar", even if it results in an empty `data.frame`.

```
> split(data, list(data$foo, data$bar))
$`1.10`
  foo bar baz qux
1   1  10   1   5
2   1  10   2   6

$`2.10`
  foo bar baz qux
3   2  10   3   7

$`1.20`
[1] foo bar baz qux
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`2.20`
  foo bar baz qux
4   2  20   4   8
```

**Option 2**: Dropping empty "levels" of the combination of "foo" and "bar"--like you do in your expected output.

```
> split(data, list(data$foo, data$bar), drop=TRUE)
$`1.10`
  foo bar baz qux
1   1  10   1   5
2   1  10   2   6

$`2.10`
  foo bar baz qux
3   2  10   3   7

$`2.20`
  foo bar baz qux
4   2  20   4   8
```

Comment: another option along same lines is `split(data, paste(data$foo, data$bar))`

Comment: @eddi, of course. I'm just using `split` the way it is designed/documented, providing a `list` of grouping factors when splitting by more than one factor. The `paste` solution does away with the need to use `drop`. Do you see any advantages of `paste` over `interaction` (which is what `split` uses by default)? I seem to remember seeing an answer on SO where `paste` was considerably faster than `interaction`, but can't find it right now.

Comment: afaik `interaction` just adds a lot of extra stuff (and then eventually does `paste`) that's just not needed for this particular case

Comment: thanks, it didn't look like it was `split` I needed from the manual

Answer (score 3):

`dlply` from `plyr` is designed for exactly this purpose:

```
require(plyr)    
dlply( data , .(foo , bar) )

$`1.10`
  foo bar baz qux
1   1  10   1   5
2   1  10   2   6

$`2.10`
  foo bar baz qux
1   2  10   3   7

$`2.20`
  foo bar baz qux
1   2  20   4   8
```

Comment: I've never fully gotten the hang of "plyr", but +1 for sharing alternatives!

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks. I am waiting for eddi to post the `data.table` solution.... :-)

Comment: I see your emoticon, but would `data.table` benefit at all from such a structure? I don't think so. I would guess that `key`s take care of that to a large extent.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes I think so. It was just in jest as I saw eddi had visited this question and he is a `data.table` whizz.

Comment: @SimonO101 - it's a bit of a perversion using `data.table` for this - you *could*, but I don't see the point - the appropriate thing to do in `data.table` framework would be **not** to do this step, as I can't think of too many cases where it's worth doing this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is like @Ananda's solution but uses `interaction`:

```
> split(data,interaction(data$foo,data$bar))
$`1.10`
  foo bar baz qux
1   1  10   1   5
2   1  10   2   6

$`2.10`
  foo bar baz qux
3   2  10   3   7

$`1.20`
[1] foo bar baz qux
<0 rækker> (eller 0-længde row.names)

$`2.20`
  foo bar baz qux
4   2  20   4   8

> split(data,interaction(data$foo,data$bar), drop=TRUE)
$`1.10`
  foo bar baz qux
1   1  10   1   5
2   1  10   2   6

$`2.10`
  foo bar baz qux
3   2  10   3   7

$`2.20`
  foo bar baz qux
4   2  20   4   8
```

Comment: Do you think that as this is ostensibly the same answer as @AnandaMahto but using a different method to create the grouping variable it might be better served as a comment or edit to Ananda's answer?

Comment: @Simono101 I posted an initial version while he was posting his. Then I edited after I saw his answer...so...what should I do...

Comment: @SimonO101, better yet, look at the code for `split.default` or the explanation of `f` from the help page for "split". The `f` argument is exactly `interaction`.

Comment: @Thomas That's up to you really. I was just asking the question that's all. I like both answers :-)